# How to parse file based on different patterns in UNIX shell scripting

Tags: text-processing

I have a file which looks like below:

```
 S123456789^ABC|00||00||ZZ|MW00021C|ZZ|207RI0200X~LX|1~SV2|6666|FG>FG997|879.5|UN|4~DTP|472|D8|20150213~REF|6R|JHYU0003707988-1~LIN||N4|67202004164~LX|2~SV2|1234|FG>BP990|879.5|UN|12~DTP|472|D8|20170413~REF|6R|ABCD0003707988-1~LIN||N4|67202004908~
```

I want to extract the `1` next to `LX`, the `FG997` next to `SV2|****|HC> ,879.5` next to it and then `4` next to `UN,20150213` next to `DTP|472|D8`, 67202004164 next to LIN||N4 and then again `2` next to `LX` and same follows.

Can someone help me achieve this using UNIX.

I have many huge files to be parsed in this manner.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange U&L.  Suggest you tidy up the formatting (indent 4 spaces for fixed font etc) and include an example of what the output file should look like (as well as your wording)

Comment: The result I am looking for is: S123456789,1,FG997,879.5,4,20150213,67202004164,2,BP990,879.5,12,20170413,67202004908

Comment: The pattern, LX, SV2, UN, DTP, LIN will be constant across the data I need to extract.

Comment: I have no idea this would work but tried this :awk '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if ($i ~ / LX|SV2|UN|DTP|LIN |/) {
            printf "%s %s ", $i, $(i + 1)
        }
    }
    print ""
}'   which did not work

Comment: putt all those info in your question, not in comments

Answer (score 0):

If all the lines of your file have the same structure, you can use awk like bellow.

```
$ awk -F"[|^~>]" -v OFS="," '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "Field",i,"---value:",$i}' <<<"$a"

#Output will be like:
Field,1,---value:,S123456789
Field,2,---value:,ABC
Field,3,---value:,00
Field,4,---value:,
Field,5,---value:,00
Field,6,---value:,
Field,7,---value:,ZZ
Field,8,---value:,MW00021C
Field,9,---value:,ZZ
Field,10,---value:,207RI0200X
Field,11,---value:,LX
Field,12,---value:,1
Field,13,---value:,SV2
Field,14,---value:,6666
Field,15,---value:,FG
Field,16,---value:,FG997
##More fields here - goes up to 51 ##
```

The awk `-F` defines the delimiters (input fields separator), and can be more than one chars.
In my example above i use chars `|`,`^`,`~`,`>` as delimiters to force awk to split the line in more pieces.
You can add more delimiters to force awk to split fields in even more pieces.
PS: variable $a in my example has the text of your question.

Since you identify which fields you want , you can then build a script like bellow to print the required fields:

```
$ awk -F"[|^~>]" -v OFS="," '{print $1,$12,$16,etc}' <<<"$a"
```

OFS defines the output separator that print will use to print the fields.

Regarding printing in awk, note that :
* When we print something like `'{print $1,$2}'` these two fields are separated by the OFS (comma in above example) --> `field1,field2`
* When we print something like `'{print $1 $2}'` awk prints the two fields concatenated - one after the other without separation between --> `field1field2`

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing is a breeze with `Perl`.

```
perl -lne '
   BEGIN{ $SKIP = qr/(?:[^|]+[|])/;  $, = ","; }

   print map { s/[~].*[|]/,/;  y/|/,/;  s/,?$//r; }
     /
        ^[^^]+
        | (?: LX  [|] )              \K \d+
        | (?: SV2 [|] \d+ [|] FG[>] )\K     $SKIP{2}
        | (?: UN  [|] )              \K \d+ $SKIP{3} \d+
        | (?: LIN [|][|] $SKIP )     \K \d+
     /xg;

' yourfile
```

## Explanation:

`-l` => `ORS=FS=\n` `-n` => `dont print unless asked to` `-e` => what follows is `Perl` code. `$,` => `OFS`

`BEGIN` block defines a regex which skips past one pipe-delimited field. We `can` (read as `box` and not `ability`) this regex coz it appears in multiple times later on when we have to skip 2 pipe-delimited fields and sometimes 3. This makes the `regex` look less horrendous.

The /.../xg returns all list of matches (only those appearing to the right of \K) then the map { ... } does some massaging and result printed to stdout.

## Output

```
S123456789,1,FG997,879.5,4,20150213,67202004164,2,BP990,879.5,12,20170413,67202004908
```